# Using an object returned from Html.RenderAction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, html.renderpartial

I am using Html.RenderAction in my View to call a method that is in my controller. The controller method returns a custom object, I want to know how would I be able to use this returned object in the view.

View

```
//at the top
@model ServiceCheckerUI.Models.DeleteDeliverableModel

@{ Html.RenderAction("retrieveDeliverableInfo","DeliverableManagement", new {uniqueId = element});}

//Trying to use the model property
Model.deliverableResponse.{properties}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult retrieveDeliverableInfo(string uniqueId){
    var response = _target.DoSomething();
    return PartialView("DeleteDeliverable", new DeleteDeliverableModel {deliverableResponse = response});
}
```

Model

```
namespace ServiceCheckerUI.Models
{
    public DeleteDeliverableModel
    {
        //omit
        public GetDeliverableResponse deliverableResponse {get;set}
    }
}
```

The GetDeliverableResponse object has fields like id, name etc which are strings and ints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RenderAction is used to directly write response to the page and helps in caching the partial view. Your method should return partial view instead of `GetDeliverableResponse`. You can define the partial view and use `GetDeliverableResponse` as it's model.

```
public ActionResult RetrieveDeliverableInfo(string uniqueId)
{
    var response = _target.DoSomething();
    return PartialView("_Deliverable", response );
}
```

Here `_Derliverable` would be your partial view which will have `GetDeliverableResponse` as model. 
To keep it more neat you can also Wrap the response object in a dedicated model class of `_Derliverable` like this:

```
class DerliverableModel
{
   public GetDeliverableResponse Derliverables { get; set; } 
}
```

now in your action method you need to pass the object of this model:

```
return PartialView("_Deliverable", new DerliverableModel { Derliveries = response });
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try to begin to implement and let you know if there are any issues

Comment: Ok I have set up the partial view. How would I go by using this model that I returned in the Partial View?

Comment: My main goal is to use the GetResponseObject in the view and fill up a table with the fields in the object\

Comment: Just like any other normal view. Create a razor view named _Deliverable use @model as GetDeliverableResponse. And do what ever you want to do by acessing Model property on the page.

Comment: See updated code above. I am trying to use the Model property but none of my created fields are showing up. Anything i am doing wrong?

Comment: The name of the view is DeleteDeliverable

Comment: Which view? You mean the main view?

Comment: Sorry the main view is called DeliverableManagement and the partial View is DeleteDeliverable

Comment: Ok then model on DeleteDeliverable should be the one you created and use tha view name in RenderAction method and you should be good to go.

Comment: Sorry I am very new to this, I am able to use Model.deliverableResponse however when I go underneath deliverableResponse the only thing that shows is ExtensionData, ToString(), Equals etc. How would I use the viewName in the RenderAction? The second parameter in the RenderAction is the name of the folder that the View is located in.

Comment: You have to write it as string like written in action method simply write RenderAction("DeleteDeliverable",....) keep the rest as is. this should work.

Comment: Donot use render action on Delete partial view. Render action method is to show a view like control on mail view.